# How to download flash video from this particular website?

Tags: download, flv

I recently did an interview for this news network that I'd love to feature on our startup's youtube channel. They have a web player, but it's really difficult to grab the video from there for some reason.

None of the automatic tools seem to work, and I can't find a flv link anywhere in the source :P.

Anyone have any ideas on how to download this video?:
http://watch.bnn.ca/the-pitch/december-2011/the-pitch-december-7-2011/#clip581215

Thanks!
Donny

Answer (score 0):

You can get some media files from the "View page info" or go with a browser add-on for Firefox called "Down them all" that will allow you to download the video.

Comment: Unfortunately I tried, but this one's a bit trickier than usual